# PrimeFaces Data Exporter exporting sheet on dataTable filtering

Tags: excel, jsf-2, primefaces

I used data table with lazy Load implementation to which I had the data exporter. The issue is when filtering on data table and click on enter button an excel sheet is generated by default with all data of data table. when I debugged my code the bean method is executed which I called upon action listener of data exporter. I am using primefaces 3.5.8 version. I placed Data Exporter table outside the form of data table.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask], then [mcve] and especially https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. And after that, improve your question

Comment: and ***after*** you do **all** of the above, remember that hitting Enter button submits the first commandButton it encounters next. Either add a hidden dummy commandButton before exporter button or play with tabIndex of your exporter button or look for Enter button on jQuery\javascript